# How do I move a .bat file into the startup folder?

Tags: batch-file, startup

I've tried many things, from the *move* command in the same batch file, to the *move* command in another. My failed code is
`move C:\Users\username\Desktop\batchfile.bat C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp`, and yes, I tried improving it in many different ways.

Comment: I would advise that you do not do it. The startup directory should contain only shortcuts to files, not the files themselves, so create a shortcut there instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use quotes:

```
move C:\Users\username\Desktop\batchfile.bat "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp"
```